# $c \in \mathbb{R}$ so that $g(x,y) = f(x,y)$ and $g(0,0) = c$ for $f(x,y) = \frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2} \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0)$

Tags: calculus, continuity

Given

$$f(x,y) = \frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2} \text{ for } (x,y) \neq (0,0)$$

I know that this function is continuous.

The question in my book is:

Does a $c \in \mathbb{R}$ exist, so that $g(x,y) = f(x,y)$ for $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$ and $g(0,0) = c$ the function $g$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R^2}$? If possible, state such a $c$.

To be honest, I don't really understand what's been asked for. Since $g(x,y) = f(x,y)$ wouldn't that mean that $g(0,0)$ is not defined as well?

What do we have to do here?

Comment: They're asking whether the limit $\;\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}f(x,y)\;$ exists...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since

$$\frac{x^2|y|}{x^2+y^2}=|y|\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\le|y|\frac{x^2}{x^2}=|y|\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0$$

then the function $\;g(x,y)\;$ is everywhere continuous if you define $\;g(0,0)=0\;$ ...